# ruby regular expression to gsub a particular portion of a string

Tags: ruby, regex

How to `gsub` a sub-string that `starts with` a particular character or `enclosed by` particular characters in ruby?

As for example :input is : `Prime rates[ U.S. Effective Date: 12/16/2008 ]`
I want to gsub the sub-string that is enclosed by two square braces [ and ] and want output like : `Prime Rates`

How can I do that using ruby regular expression?

Comment: What do you want the `gsub` to replace the substring into? Do you mean you want to delete the substring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
s.gsub(/\[.*\]/, "")
```

This will remove anything enclosed in `[]` assuming there is no more than one occurrence of such substring.